# How to add speed effect on content hide and show with text change on toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make some content hide and show on toggle button.Here my problem is that i am unable to add speed effect of hide and show and text change of button on click.Please Help me ! Thanks !

```
<script> 
   function toggleDescriptionHeight() {
   document.querySelector(".backwhite").classList.toggle('expanded');
}
</script>


<style>
  .backwhite{
   background-color: aqua;
   padding:15px;
   height:50px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
  .backwhite.expanded {
   height: auto;
}
</style>


<div class="container">
 <div class="backwhite">
  <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
  <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
  <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
  <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
  <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
  <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
  <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
  <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
  <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
 </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="toggleDescriptionHeight();">Toggle</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Refer: [Toggle speed effect](http://api.jqueryui.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 0):

height: auto; doesn't give toggle effect to div

If you are using jQuery, this is very easy:

```
$(".backwhite").toggle( "slow" );
```

Also you can do this with pure javascript:

```js
function toggleDescriptionHeight() {
  var el = document.querySelector(".backwhite");
  var height = el.scrollHeight;
  el.style.height = el.offsetHeight == "50" ? height+"px" : "50px";
}
```

```css
.backwhite{
   background-color: aqua;
   padding:15px;
   height:50px;
   overflow:hidden;
   transition:all .5s; //added code
   box-sizing:border-box; //added code
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="backwhite">
  <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
  <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
  <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
  <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
  <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
  <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
  <p>1. Create Ui For Email Campaign.</p>
  <p>2. Create Functionality of Email Campaign</p>
  <p>3. Create Keyword Display using Drag And Drop Functionality.</p>
 </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="toggleDescriptionHeight()">Toggle</button>
</div>
```